# refer a string or list global variable in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, global, tornado

In *python 2.7.2 + tornado 3.1.1*, how to use a global variable? I need it work on AppEngine.

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/')
            return
        # assign self.get_argument('next', '/')) to the variable next_page
        self.render('login.html')

    def post(self):
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("username"))
        # direct to next_page
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "global variable"?

Comment: Tornado will not work on App Engine. And you certainly don't want a global variable on either App Engine or Tornado.

Comment: yep, it may be a bad idea running tornado on AppEngine. But tornado supports WSGI and AppEngine do too. @Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need global variables for store `next_page` variable. Try to use sessions or memcache for it.

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache

# setup a key/value
memcache.set(key='next_page_%s' % user.id, next_page)

# get next_page
next_page = memcache.get(key='next_page_%s' % user.id)
```

We use `'next_page_%s' % user.id` with `user.id` for unigue key, otherwise every user will have only one `next_page`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the variable as being global within each function:

```
global globalvariable
```

See also [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) for more information on this issue.